# Vorpal Vantage: i'm not able to exit the interactive console programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal

What's wrong with this?

```
const Vantage = require('vantage')

const v = Vantage()
    .delimiter('$test')
    .listen(9000)
    .show()

const close = () => {
    v.exec('exit', () => {
        console.log('DONE')
    })
 }  
setTimeout(close, 1000)
```

Error:

> UI Prompt called when already mid prompt. at Object.prompt
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/ui.js:131:13)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal.prompt
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:450:8)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal.exit
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:1160:12)
>   at Session.
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal-commons.js:49:19)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal._exec
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:846:18)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal._execQueueItem
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:594:10)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal._queueHandler
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:579:10)
>   at Vorpal.vorpal.exec
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:554:24)
>   at Timeout.close [as _onTimeout]
>   (/Users/giggioz/Spaghetti/keeper/keeper-giochipiu-delegates/xxx.js:9:7)
>   at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
const Vantage = require('vantage')

Vantage()
    .delimiter('$test')
    .listen(9000)
    .show()

const close = () => {
    process.exit(1)
}
setTimeout(close, 1000)
```